# Java BigDecimal precision problems

Tags: java, bigdecimal, double-precision

I know the following behavior is an old problem, but still I don't understand.

```
System.out.println(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1);
```

Or even though I use `BigDecimal`

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1).doubleValue()
    + new BigDecimal(0.1).doubleValue()
    + new BigDecimal(0.1).doubleValue());
```

Why this result is: `0.30000000000000004` instead of: `0.3`?

How can I solve this?

Comment: You ... aren't using `BigDecimal`. You're doing *exactly the same thing* as adding the doubles. `doubleValue()` returns ... a double. See the Javadoc for `BigDecimal` on how to add/subtract/etc

Comment: Re the `double` calculations, see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  Java solves this by providing format options for output.

Comment: Why are you using `doubleValue()`??? I thought you wanted a decimal type.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you actually want is

```
new BigDecimal("0.1")
 .add(new BigDecimal("0.1"))
 .add(new BigDecimal("0.1"));
```

The `new BigDecimal(double)` constructor gets all the imprecision of the `double`, so by the time you've said `0.1`, you've already introduced the rounding error.  Using the `String` constructor avoids the rounding error associated with going via the `double`.

Comment: thanks for all!
Now... I can understand that.

´
// IT WORKS FOR MY PROBLEM
Double value= 0.1d;
BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal("0.0");
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
 total = total.add(new BigDecimal(value.toString()));
}
System.out.print(total);
 
// DON'T WORK
System.out.print(0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d);

// DON'T WORK
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1).add(new BigDecimal(0.1)).add(new BigDecimal(0.1)));

// IT WORKS
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.1").add(new BigDecimal("0.1")).add(new BigDecimal("0.1")));

// IT WORKS, BUT WITH LESS PRECISION
System.out.println(0.1f + 0.1f + 0.1f);
`

Comment: A slight correction: _"imprecision of the double"_ - this is technically not true. The double can perfectly represent `0.1` - with a mantissa of 1 and an exponent of -1. It's the conversion of a `double` to a `BigDecimal` that converts the floating point representation to a normal binary representation somewhere along the way. This is why the double constructor is flawed.

Comment: Um, what?  No, it can't.  `0.1` cannot be represented as a fraction in binary, period, which is how `double`s are represented.  A mantissa of 1 and an exponent of -1 gets you 0.5.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I was reading the binary representation of a double incorrectly.

Answer (score 11):

First **never**, never use the double constructor of BigDecimal. It may be the right thing in a few situations but mostly it isn't

If you can control your input use the BigDecimal String constructor as was already proposed. That way you get exactly what you want. If you already have a double (can happen after all), don't use the double constructor but instead the static `valueOf` method. That has the nice advantage that we get the cannonical representation of the double which mitigates the problem at least.. and the result is usually much more intuitive.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a problem of Java, but rather a problem of computers generally. The core problem lies in the conversion from decimal format (human format) to binary format (computer format). Some numbers in decimal format are not representable in binary format without infinite repeating decimals.

For example, 0.3 decimal is 0.01001100... binary But a computer has a limited "slots" (bits) to save a number, so it cannot save all the whole infinite representation. It saves only
0.01001100110011001100 (for example). But that number in decimal is no longer 0.3, but 0.30000000000000004 instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0.1).add(new BigDecimal(0.1)).add(new BigDecimal(0.1));
```

EDIT: Actually, looking over the Javadoc, this will have the same problem as the original. The constructor `BigDecimal(double)` will make a BigDecimal corresponding to the exact floating-point representation of 0.1, which is not exactly equal to 0.1.

This, however, gives the exact result, since integers CAN always be expressed exactly in floating-point representation:

```
BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(1);
BigDecimal oneTenth = one.divide(new BigDecimal(10));

BigDecimal sum = oneTenth.add(oneTenth).add(oneTenth);
```

Comment: NEVER use the `double` constructor for big decimal (well there may be some rare situations, but really it's a bad idea). If you can, use the string constructor (that will be exact), if you already have a double use `valueOf` as that way we don't get additional bogus precision...

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that 0.1 is represented with a slightly higher number e.g.

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1));
```

prints

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

The Double.toString() takes into account this representation error so you don't see it.

Similarly 0.3 is represented by a value slightly lower than it really is.

```
0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
```

If you multiply the represented value of 0.1 by 3 you don't get the represented value for 0.3, you instead get something a little higher

```
0.3000000000000000166533453693773481063544750213623046875
```

This is not just a representation error but also a rounding error caused by the operations.  This is more than the Double.toString() will correct and so you see the rounding error.

The moral of the story, if you use `float` or `double` also round the solution appropriately.

```
double d = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1;
System.out.println(d);
double d2 = (long)(d * 1e6 + 0.5) / 1e6; // round to 6 decimal places.
System.out.println(d2);
```

prints

```
0.30000000000000004
0.3
```