# converting python to java float vs double

Tags: java, python

I need to convert the [following python code](https://github.com/asdfhamiltonian/planets/blob/master/luna.py) to Java and remember from the past that handling decimal values must be done carefully otherwise the results will not be accurate.
My question is, can I use **doubles** for all non-interger values given doubles are more accurate that floats?

Here is my start of the conversion:

Python code

```
def degrees(rads):
    return (rads/pi)*180


def radians(degrees):
return (degrees/180 * pi)


def fnday(y, m, d, h):
a = 367 * y - 7 * (y + (m + 9) // 12) // 4 + 275 * m // 9
a += d - 730530 + h / 24
return a
```

Java conversion

```
public double degress(double rads)
{
    return (rads/PI)*180;
}

public double radians(double degrees)
{
    return (degrees/180 * PI);
}

public double fnday(int y, int m, int d, int h)
{
    double a = 367 * y - 7 * (y + (m + 9) / 12) / 4 + 275 * m / 9;
    a += d - 730530 + h / 24;
    return a;
}
```

I know it may be a simple answer but I need to know the postion of the moon and sun for the app and do not want to rely on an api for this data.  I simple want to put in the latitude and longitdue and get the sun and moon rise and set times.

Comment: Using an API like mine ([Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/astro/package-summary.html)) would be much easier and enables good precision (fine agreement with official USNO-data) and offers easy transformation of results to `java.time`-types. On Android, you can use [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A).

Answer (score 3):

Using a `double` for each variable would suffice; however, you have an issue that results from integer division:

```
double a = 367 * y - 7 * (y + (m + 9) / 12) / 4 + 275 * m / 9;
```

If I were you, I'd change `y`, `m`, `d`, and `h` to all be `double`s, so you retain the decimal places when dividing:

```
public double fnday(double y, double m, double d, double h) {
    double a = 367 * y - 7 * (y + (m + 9) / 12) / 4 + 275 * m / 9;

    a += d - 730530 + h / 24;

    return a;
}
```

Comment: missed that.   I will make that change.  Appreciate the info.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a really big precision, the best way is use,
 [java.lang.BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), that extends from java.math.Number.

You can even use your existing doubles if you need:

```
double d = 67.67;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
```

But you will need to use the methods from the class like this:

```
public BigDecimal degress(BigDecimal rads)
{
    BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal(PI);
    return (rads.divide(pi))*180;
}
```

Comment: Given I only need accuracy to within 5 minutes do you think I should use BigDecimal instead of double as I am at the start of the conversion process?

Comment: @timv It's sure to be much more accurate, I can't figure out how much precision do you need, but if I were you, and I'm looking for more precision, I would use that. Be careful be cause if you initialize BigDecimal with doubles you drag with it the precision, look it also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795364/java-bigdecimal-precision-problems

Comment: Funny to suggest to use BigDecimal to then use it with its deprecated double constructor.

Comment: Maybe I can keep them as doubles during the conversion, run some tests with a few locations (lats, lngs) and then test again replacing the doubles with BigDecimals.   I will then answer my question with my findings.

Comment: Fantastic! @timv Let me know how it worked for you :D

Comment: Big precision is not achieved by using `BigDecimal` instead of `double` but rather by choosing a suitable astronomical algorithm!