# Java BigDecimal to String

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have below piece of code and my precision is getting lost while converting `BigDecimal` to `String`. Any help on this really appreciated.
Expected result : `95.10000000000000%`
Actual Result : `95.09999999999999%`

```
public static String getAsString(Object value) 
{
    if (value == null)
        return null;

    if (value.toString().length() == 0)
        return null;

    BigDecimal inputVal = new BigDecimal(value.toString());

    if (inputVal == new BigDecimal(0))
        return "";

    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(Locale.US);
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(14); 
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(14);
    if (numberFormat instanceof DecimalFormat) {
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) numberFormat;
        df.setNegativePrefix("(");
        df.setNegativeSuffix("%)");
    }

    String num = null;
    num = numberFormat.format(new BigDecimal(95.1).divide(new BigDecimal(100)));

    return num;
}
```

Comment: What input do you give it to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Also, `inputVal == new BigDecimal(0)` will always fail. No object will ever be the same as a newly created one. Use `equals` instead.

Comment: @marstran While you're right about the wrong reference comparision, `equals` isn't the right thing to use, as `equals` for `BigDecimal.equals` takes the scale into account (look at the docs).

You should instead use `BigDecimal.compareTo`.

Answer (score 11):

With this instance creation

```
new BigDecimal(95.1)
```

you are [losing some precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795364/java-bigdecimal-precision-problems). What you actually can do is to use the string constructor:

```
new BigDecimal("95.1")
```

Another way for your case is to use the factory methods:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(95.1)
BigDecimal.valueOf(100)
```

Internally these use the string representation of those numbers to create a `BigDecimal` object.

Answer (score 3):

In this case using the `new BigDecimal(double x)` and `double` as an argument and it happens that doubles can't represent `x.xxxx` exactly. So `x.xxxx` is "transformed" to the closest possible double, which is `x.0000xxxxxxxxxxxzzzzzzzzzzyyyyy` and that's what your BigDecimal shows.

So, here the solution could be you can use the `String` constructor or the `valueOf()` method, to create the canonical represent of your `double`d value.

By changing your line

```
num = numberFormat.format(new BigDecimal(95.1).divide(new BigDecimal(100)));
```

to

```
num = numberFormat.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(95.1).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)));
```

or

```
num = numberFormat.format(new BigDecimal("95.1").divide(new BigDecimal("100")));
```

should give you the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 BigDecimal inputVal = new BigDecimal(value.toString()).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: It doesn't give the expected result. Check your answer please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setScale` and then convert to a String.

I see you want to print 14 digits, so set the scale to 14, and use rounding up.

```
BigDecimal inputVal = new BigDecimal(95.10000000000000).setScale(14, RoundingMode.UP);
```

Then call `toString` and add the % etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string value

```
num = numberFormat.format(new BigDecimal("95.1").divide(new BigDecimal("100")));
```